# Java Applet becomes a blank white screen when it's done

Tags: java, applet, awt, paint, java-2d

All my applet does is draw something, step by step.

My `update()` block goes something like:

```
public void update(Graphics g)
{
  if (!done)
  {
    while (!doneDrawing)
    {
      imageGraphics.drawSomething(...);
      g.drawImage(image);
    }
    done = true;
  }
}
```

The `done` variable prevents the loop from going through the whole drawing process again when it's done, and I can make the applet draw the drawing one more time by setting it to false.

I put the applet on a webpage, and it works as expected, but when I switch tabs/windows and come back, all I see is the white screen (using Chrome). When I press a button that sets `done` to false, the applet redraws the draw, looks all fine and dandy, until I switch tabs.

I tried to have the applet constantly draw the picture on the screen even if `done == true`, but that didn't seem to change anything.

```
public void update(Graphics g)
{
  if (!done)
  {
    while (!doneDrawing)
    {
      imageGraphics.drawSomething(...);
      g.drawImage(image);
    }
    done = true;
  }
  g.drawImage(image);
}
```

EDIT: The second chunk of code above actually did fix the problem. My web browser just didn't want to change to the updated code until I closed/reopened the tab, rather than just refresh. However, I'm going by Andrew's suggestion to start learning JFrames/JPanels.

Comment: 1) It seems the code is using the `update(Graphics)` method in an entirely wrong way when it goes into a loop.  See [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for the correct way to do animated painting. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) Do this in a `JPanel` in a `JFrame` 1st, then put the panel in the applet once it works.

Comment: If I remeber correctly, don't applets have methods that are called when they are hidden/shown, as in when you switch back?  You could just set done = false when the applet is "shown" again.

Comment: @csga5000 For my code, setting done = false will cause the applet to go throught the whole drawing animation again. This one creates randomly generated images, and the final product is stored in `image`. So after the applet is done, I want it to just display the final image. But switching tabs and stuff just leaves a white screen.